# What is UIViewControllerWrapperView?

Tags: objective-c, view, uiview

I programed  when one moment, i called the superview method from my view from viewController and with a NSLog("%@", [myView superview]); I saw wrote : >

What is this ?

Thx you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a private view used by the framework. You're not supposed to modify it or whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

A view must belong to a view hierarchy for its contraints (position, size) to be set.
The UIViewControllerWrapperView is the parent of a controllers view, which has not been added as a subview of another view.

As an example: UIViewController has a view property and a collectionView property. The collectionView resides within the view in the view hierarchy.
The view if of type UIViewControllerWrapperView.