# iOS: Finding the uiviewcontroller's class name from view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

My TabBarViewController has added too many levels of ViewControllers/Views. I have to go like this in -(void)viewDidAppear:animated to configure the correct view I want:

```
[[[[[self.view.subviews[0] subviews][0] subviews][0] subviews][0] subviews][0] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

This code is ugly and no one can understand it.

I wanted to find the corresponds view controller/view and configure it there. I tried

```
[[[[self.view.subviews[0] subviews][0] subviews][0] subviews][0] subviews][0] class]
```

However, it returns UIView, which wasn't helpful to me at all.

EDIT:
[image: View hierarchy]

I am trying to access the UIViewControllerWrapperView in order to change its autoresizing property. However, according to this post: [What is UIViewControllerWrapperView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830604/what-is-uiviewcontrollerwrapperview) It seems it is not accessible. I am still fighting how to find the correct (or the closest) view controller to change its property so that I have no or less [subview objectAtIndex:0] stuff.

What I wanted to do is

Comment: I am just not getting what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Unheilig Hey, I have edited the post and posted a screenshot. Hopefully it can make some sense to you now.

Answer (score 0):

I think no one understands it because the way you are doing it is really non-standard and a bad idea.  What view are you looking for?  You shouldn't find it like this.  The standard way would be to use a XIB or Storyboard and connect the view from there to your ViewController with an IBOutlet.  You would then just reference it that way.

You can watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYS0sCFWOSo) on how to connect things with storyboards, if you don't know how.

If you are programatically adding this view, you should just make a property in your ViewController and save a reference to your view in that property.  Like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) YourViewClassType *fancyView;
```

then when you create it just set fancyView to your view you created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I get this project from someone else and I know very litter about it. They used storyboard but I can't change the flexible height there. I don't know why.

Comment: You don't need to change it there, but you can connect that view from the storyboard to its view controller class.  Then you can change it in  your view controller.